# sshd "listen on all interfaces" behaviour, OSX and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, iptables, ssh-tunnel

Given an extra loopback interface in the `127.0.0.X` (`X`>`1`) range on BoxA (which can be running either OSX or Linux), I want to bind port 22 of this extra loopback interface to a forward SSH tunnel (ie. local port forward) that is pointed at BoxB.

On OSX this works fine (strangely, in retrospect). [Taking `X`=`2`] after bringing up the loopback alias with `ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.2 up`, SSH can establish a tunnel with `ssh -NfL 127.0.0.2:22:localhost:22 BoxB`. Then in a new shell on BoxA, `ssh 127.0.0.2` logs me into BoxB.

On Ubuntu, I can bring up the loopback alias on BoxA, but when trying to establish the SSH tunnel, `ssh` complains about not being able to bind (and hence forward) BoxA's port 22. The subsequent `ssh 127.0.0.2` (in a new shell on BoxA) gives a fingerprint warning, which if bypassed, logs me back into BoxA. Makes sense - `sshd` on BoxA is listening to *all* interfaces.

Looking at the `sshd_config` in each, both are configured to listen on `0.0.0.0` (and `::` for IPv6).

`lsof` for OSX gives:

```
launchd       1           root   40u  IPv6 0xddfcabed61001f0d      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd       1           root   41u  IPv4 0xddfcabed6100413d      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd       1           root   43u  IPv6 0xddfcabed61001f0d      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
launchd       1           root   44u  IPv4 0xddfcabed6100413d      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

and for Ubuntu:

```
sshd       1287              0    3u     IPv4           21903340        0t0        TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
```

So both are listening on all interfaces, though I'm not sure why OSX uses 4 processes. In any case, Ubuntu gives the expected behaviour. Why does OSX behave differently?

The follow up question of course, is how to make Ubuntu behave like OSX in this regard.

While I wish for the `sshd_config` to have state, wildcards and/or logical operators (e.g. "do not listen on `127.0.0.*`; listen on `127.0.0.1`") like `iptables`, it doesn't seem to be the case...

Comment: No need to play with X. Just use `ssh -NfL  22:localhost:22 BoxB` and connect to tunneled port as localhost:22

Comment: It gives a channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip failure, with "bind: Address already in use" for good measure (on Ubuntu).

Comment: That's means you already bind something to the same port. If you having multiple tunnels to other boxes or some local service already used it for some purpose, simply use different local port that not in use: `ssh -NfL 20001:localhost:22 BoxA`,  `ssh -NfL 20002:localhost:22 BoxB`, `ssh -NfL 20003:localhost:22 BoxC` and so on... Use `netstat -lntp` to spot free/buzy local ports

Comment: Yes, sshd on BoxA is using port 22, clearly visible in the `lsof` output. The entire question is why OSX allows forwarding :22 on new loopback interfaces, and Ubuntu does not...

Answer (score 1):

That's reproducible using [`socat`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/socat/socat.1.en.html) (`1.7.3.2-2`, not `1.7.3.1-2+deb9u1` which *ignores* `reuseport`) on Debian (so similar for Ubuntu):

```
term1$ socat -d -d  TCP4-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,fork -
2018/08/03 08:20:43 socat[25084] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555

term2$ socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:5555,bind=127.0.0.2,reuseaddr,fork -
2018/08/03 08:21:00 socat[25085] E bind(5, {AF=2 127.0.0.2:5555}, 16): Address already in use
2018/08/03 08:21:00 socat[25085] N exit(1)
```

Now if you add `reuseport` *on both*:

```
term1$ socat -d -d  TCP4-LISTEN:5555,reuseaddr,reuseport,fork -
2018/08/03 08:21:28 socat[25086] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:5555

term2$ socat -d -d TCP4-LISTEN:5555,bind=127.0.0.2,reuseaddr,reuseport,fork -
2018/08/03 08:21:56 socat[25092] N listening on AF=2 127.0.0.2:5555


otherterm$ netstat -tnlp 2>/dev/null|grep :5555 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:5555          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25092/socat         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5555            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25086/socat
```

Using an other `socat` or netcat to connect will show it's properly routed to the correct listening `socat` depending on the IP address.

So the behaviour difference is most certainly on how the [`bind`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/bind.2.en.html) and [`setsockopt`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/setsockopt.2.en.html) calls are done on MacOS and Ubuntu for ssh (maybe launchd has a role to play too?). Using `strace`, this is added in the working `socat` case:

```
 setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
```

---

**UPDATE**:
While I will address the letter of the OP's question: make it work, I also think the question doesn't tell about the broader goal and this goal might be achieved with an entirely different solution.

So to alter `sshd` and `ssh` behaviour when they bind a socket, it's possible to use a [`dlsym()`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/dlsym.3.en.html) wrapper that will alter `bind(3)`'s function behaviour before the real [`bind(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/bind.2.en.html) syscall.

compile the file `reuseport-wrapper.c` below with:

`gcc -shared -fPIC -o reuseport-wrapper.so reuseport-wrapper.c -ldl`

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stddef.h> /* NULL */

int bind(int socket, const struct sockaddr *address, socklen_t address_len) {
    static const int optval=1;
    static int (*orig_bind)(int, const struct sockaddr *,socklen_t)=NULL;

    if (orig_bind == NULL && (orig_bind=dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"bind")) == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (address != NULL && (address->sa_family == AF_INET || address->sa_family == AF_INET6)) {
        if (setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof optval) != 0) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return orig_bind(socket, address, address_len);
}
```

This will put a wrapper on `bind(3)` to always set `SO_REUSEPORT` before binding an `inet` or `inet6` socket.

Place it somewhere (eg as `/usr/local/lib/reuseport-wrapper.so` but it really doesn't matter since it's explicitely loaded like would a plugin).

Edit `/etc/default/ssh` and add:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/reuseport-wrapper.so
```

restart the ssh server (eg `service ssh restart`)

And run any other tool (including `ssh`) as root (see below why) with `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/reuseport-wrapper.so` exported. For example:

```
$ sudo su -
[...]
# LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/reuseport-wrapper.so ssh -NfL 127.0.0.2:22:localhost:22 userB@BoxB
```

This command has to be started as root for two reasons: port 22 requires root to bind to it, and even with some additional capability, there's an additional restriction described in [`socket(7)`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages/socket.7.en.html):

> SO_REUSEPORT (since Linux 3.9)
>       Permits multiple AF_INET or AF_INET6 sockets to be bound to an identical socket address. This option must be set on each socket
>   (including the first socket) prior to calling bind(2) on the socket.
>   **To prevent port hijacking, all of the processes binding to the same address must have the same effective UID**. This option can be
>   employed with both TCP and UDP sockets.

Once this is done:

```
# netstat -tnlp |grep -w 22
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:22            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      157/ssh             
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      143/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      143/sshd
```

And the tunnel will work as expected.

Comment: Good information, thanks. Not sure if I accept it as an answer per se, as it doesn't fix the problem (assuming its fixable at all), but provides useful information...

Comment: Added a "working" solution just to underline something else should be sought. It's possible the question is hiding [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).